# Error : null value being entered in table through jsp code

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, tomcat, database-connection

My code snippets are as below :

ShopRegister2.jsp :

```
<% 
session = request.getSession();
session.setAttribute("s_id", s_id);
out.println("Your id is : "+s_id);
        %>          
        <br>
        Please note it for further use.!<br>
        <form name="register" method="post" onsubmit=" return reg_form()"     action="ShopRegister3.jsp"><br>
        Enter your name : <input type="text" name="s_name" id="s_name"><br>
        Enter your Location : <input type="text" name="s_location" id="s_location"><br>
        Enter your password : <input type="password" name="s_password" id="s_password">    <br>
        Confirm Password : <input type="password" name="c_s_password"     id="c_s_password"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"><br>
        </form><br>
```

ShopRegister3.jsp :

```
String s_name=null, s_password=null, s_location=null;
int s_id = 0;   

session.setAttribute("s_name", s_name);
session.setAttribute("s_password", s_password);  
session.setAttribute("s_location", s_location);

String s_id_string=(String)request.getParameter("s_id");
s_id = session.getAttribute("s_id") != null ? (Integer) session.getAttribute("s_id") : 0 ;          
s_name=(String)session.getAttribute("s_name");
s_password=(String)session.getAttribute("s_password");
s_location=(String)session.getAttribute("s_location");

//entering values into Shop table
PreparedStatement s_insert = con.prepareStatement("insert into ShopSystem.Shop values(?,?,?,?)");
s_insert.setInt(1, s_id);
s_insert.setString(2, s_password);                  
s_insert.setString(3, s_location);
s_insert.setString(4, s_name);
int c = s_insert.executeUpdate();
//checking whether the value was inserted successfully
if(c>0)
{    %>
S_ID = <%= s_id %> has been registered successfully.<br>
<%  response.sendRedirect("ShopMenu3.jsp");     
} %>
```

In the above code the server is directing to ShopMenu3.jsp after running ShopRegister3.jsp
Yet in my database, null values are being entered for the attributes : name, password and location.
I have tried many things..., where exactly seems to be the error?

Answer (score 2):

Your session variables are always set to null;
Use:

```
s_name=(String)request.getParameter("s_name");
s_password=(String)request.getParameter("s_password");
s_location=(String)request.getParameter("s_location");
```

To get the values before setting them in the session

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that is the problem?

```
String s_name=null, s_password=null, s_location=null;
```

And then you set session to this null values.

Answer (score -1):

You have to first request that parameter before setSession statement;
so in `ShopRegister3.jsp`, after `s_name` initialization to `null´.
Request that parameter like:

```
s_name = request.getParameter("s_name");
```

Now you can `setSession` for this variable; it will not return `null` for `s_name` variable now.